# Should I use the yield curve or swap curve to find the value of my swap?

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rate-swap

The PiVe Capital Swap Spread Trades' case study (in *Fixed Income Securities* from Pietro Veronesi) suggested that in pricing a swap, using a swap curve appears to be the most reasonable methodology.

However, he later said that we use data of LIBOR rates for maturities up to 6 months and then bootstrapping to find and derive the swap rate for Z(t,t+0.5).

Based on my understanding, the swap rate will be higher than the LIBOR due to counterparty risk. However, considering most swap are transacted through dealers, should we be using LIBOR instead of the swap rate? I am not very sure on the rationale for using the swap rate.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/66407/54838) helpful. Generally, one shouldn't mix libro rates (ignoring that libor is gone now anyways). In general, [Everything You Always Wanted to Know About Multiple Interest Rate Curve Bootstrapping but Were Afraid to Ask](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2219548) is the go to source.